# Error JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory inside Docker with Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: android, docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

this is the first time when I use Gitlab CI/CD and Docker

I have a small pipeline with several jobs:

```bash
before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
 
stages:
  - build

create common folder to store build:
  stage: build
  needs: []
  tags:
     - shell
  script:
    - mkdir popa
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./popa

 
get debug apk build:
  stage: build
  needs: [create common folder to store build]
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - ./gradlew app:assembleDebug
    - mv app/build/outputs/apk/debug/*.apk ./popa
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./popa

get release apk build:
  stage: build
  needs: [create common folder to store build]
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - ./gradlew app:assembleRelease
    - mv app/build/outputs/apk/release/*.apk ./popa
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./popa

get release aab build:
  stage: build
  needs: [create common folder to store build]
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - ./gradlew app:bundleRelease
    - mv app/build/outputs/bundle/release/*.aab ./popa
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./popa

get one folder build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - shell
  needs: [get debug apk build, get release apk build, get release aab build]
  script:
    - echo "DONE"
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./popa
```

and when I use the Shell executor (with macOS setup) everything is fine. But when I use Docker I get the following error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Users/qfunz/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

I check this in my macOS

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

and get this

```
/Users/qfunz/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
```

so I added this in Gitlab CI/CD Settings - Variables (JAVA_HOME = /Users/qfunz/.sdkman/candidates/java/current)

When I run in Docker

```
java
```

I get nothing.
I understand that Docker has the personal file system, but I can't understand how to fix this problem

Comment: which docker image you are using ?

Comment: @Swayangjit gitlab/gitlab-runner

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of the customized docker images(**jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android**) which are meant to use for android builds

```
image: jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android

cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_ID}
  paths:
    - .gradle/

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - export JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java"
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
stages:
.............
.............
```

Comment: same result as above (ERROR)

Comment: @qfunz Updated the answer. Can you please try that